# How to solve syntaxError in GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, graphql, schema

I have the following syntax error:

> throw (0, _syntaxError.syntaxError)(this._lexer.source, token.start,
>   "Expected ".concat(kind, ", found ").concat(getTokenDesc(token)));

and this is my schema:

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: buildSchema('type RootQuery{' +
        'events: [String!]!' +
        '}' +
        'type RootMutation{' +
        'createEvent(name: String): String' +
        '}' +
        'schema{' +
        'query: RootQuery' +
        'mutation: RootMutation' +
        '}'),
    rootValue: {
        events: () =>{
            return ['Hello1','Hello2','Hello3'];
        },
        createEvent: (args)=>{
            const eventName = args.name;
            return eventName;
        }

    },
    graphiql: true,
}));
```

I'm trying for hours to understand where in the schema syntax I was wrong, and I can't find it.

Comment: why is this tagged mongo

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a few commas.

This is the working code:

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: buildSchema('type RootQuery{' +
        'events: [String!]!' +
        '},' +
        'type RootMutation{' +
        'createEvent(name: String): String' +
        '},' +
        'schema{' +
        'query: RootQuery,' +
        'mutation: RootMutation' +
        '}'),
    rootValue: {
        events: () =>{
            return ['Hello1','Hello2','Hello3'];
        },
        createEvent: (args)=>{
            const eventName = args.name;
            return eventName;
        }
    },
    graphiql: true
}));
```